# Why is the value of "Sum CPUCreditBalance" so high?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-cloudwatch

I have 3 EC2 instances which are created by Elastic Beanstalk. Their current CPU Credit Balance are as the following:

[image]

And this is the monitoring page in Elastic Beanstalk:

[image]

Why is "Sum CPUCreditBalance" equal to 1.8K?

As you can see from the first picture, the CPU credit balances of the 3 EC2 instances are all below 120. 120 * 3 = 360 is far smaller than 1.8K = 1800.

How is 1.8K calculated?

Here are the options I used when creating Sum CPUCreditBalance:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SUM() isn't a meaningful aggregation of a sampled statistic like CPU Credit Balance.  You're adding up all the values from the samples recorded in the time range, and that provides no useful information for this type of measurement.

SUM() only makes sense when the metric itself is a raw count of things per sampling period, such as the number HTTP requests or errors.

> `Sum` -- All values submitted for the matching metric added together. This statistic can be useful for determining the total volume of a metric.
>
> https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/cloudwatch_concepts.html#Statistic

Answer (score 1):

It is the sum of all data points (CPU Credit Balance) in the graph.

Roughly calculating data points: 11x20 + 7x50 + 110x11 = 1780